# Chrome DevTools: Is there any way to calculate Queuing Time using the Network API?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

Using the [Chrome DevTools Network API events](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/), what is the formula to calculate queuing time?

Here is some more information about queuing time from [this source](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/understanding-resource-timing):

[image]

[image]